# ¿Cómo imprimo saltos de línea en un HTML desde un Java Bean?

Tags: java, html, java-ee

Tanto con `\n` como con `<br/>` no realiza el salto de línea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe la solución a este problema?

Comment: Por favor fijate de hacer copy paste del código en lugar de una foto. El problema que tenes seguramente es que la salida del texto que estás devolviedo está siendo escapada para html osea te convierte los tags en &lt; y &gt;

Comment: ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Edita la pregunta como texto y agrega como estás sacando ese texto al html. JSP, JSTL, jQuery, y/o alguna otra librería.

Comment: Estoy utilizando JSP / JSF.

Answer (score 1):

Tal como lo describes es imposible que funcione un "\n" y mucho menos una etiqueta html como "br", ya que en la vista asumo que estás haciendo referencia a la variable "txt" del Bean. Lo que te recomiendo es que coloques los datos que generas en el Bean dentro de un arrayList:

```
private List<Object[]> listaDatos = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

Luego en la función, dentro del bucle "for" vas agregando los datos al arrayList:

```
listaDatos.add(new Object[]{picks.get(i),picksStr.get(i));
```

Finalmente en la vista (por ejemplo usando PrimeFaces), desplegar los datos dentro de una tabla:

```
<p:dataTable
    id="tblEjemplo"
    widgetVar="tblEjemplo"
    var="data"
    value="#{Bean.listaDatos}"> 

    <p:column> 
        <p:outputLabel value="#{data[0]}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column> 
        <p:outputLabel value="#{data[1]}"/>
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```